# How to Size the Cards on bootstrap

Tags: html, web, design-patterns, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to size the cards deck, I have 3 cards and I'm trying to adjust them to be `col-3` but it didn't work, I'm using `bootstrap 4.1x` version I don't know what's wrong in my code

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card-deck" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <div class="card col-sm-3">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1181316/pexels-photo-1181316.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-sm-3">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2277784/pexels-photo-2277784.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-sm-3">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1181605/pexels-photo-1181605.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        <img src="..." alt="..." class="rounded-circle">
        <img src="..." alt="..." class="rounded-circle">
        <img src="..." alt="..." class="rounded-circle">
        </div>
```

Comment: how is it looking in your page? I tried to make a jsfiddle of your code and it's looking fine https://jsfiddle.net/1kgn5a8w/

Comment: What kind of output does want you using col-3? Can you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use different col for different resolutions

`class="card col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"`

and you are showing only 3 cards in a row so if you multiply with 4 you will get 12 which is maximum col value so it will display equally on your page.

Answer (score 0):

try `col-sm-4` if you are trying to display the cards with equal width on the page.
also can you elaborate on what exactly the issue is?